# Creating a transparent GUI overlay on top of a Full screen game in python

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, overlay, pygtk

I am looking to make a transparent GUI on top of a fullscreen game application. I have looked and studied this post on SO: [How to make window overlay (on top of browser,games exc.) with wxPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54503994/how-to-make-window-overlay-on-top-of-browser-games-exc-with-wxpython)

I tried it out - and unfortunately it works well to show a transparent GUI when you are working on a desktop , but when you are running a fullscreen application the transparent window is hidden.

Can this be done with wxPython? If not, is there another toolkit or method people are aware of?

Answer (score 1):

You could use

https://github.com/wxWidgets/Phoenix/blob/master/demo/Overlay.py

in combination with the [wxNativeWindow](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_native_window.html).

Not sure it this is implemented in the Python wrapper though, it is listed [here](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.Window.html) but not linked.

See also at
[How to make a wx window parent of another application's window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40923352/how-to-make-a-wx-window-parent-of-another-applications-window)

Comment: Hi Joe, this looks very promising! Can you talk me through making this example extended to include the wxNativeWindow you reference? Perhaps through an example?

Comment: Have you checked if the wxNativeWindow is implements in wxPython?

Comment: I see this : https://docs.wxpython.org/wx.GraphicsContext.html?highlight=nativewindow#wx.GraphicsContext.CreateFromNativeWindow but am really not well placed to know if this is what you refer to.

Comment: I also saw that, it probably uses the wxNativeWindow behind the scenes. But you have to check in the sources. I could not find it. You can try https://discuss.wxpython.org/

Comment: Is there some other alternative method using some other Python bindings or libraries @joe?

Comment: Do you have to use wx? If not, PyQt 5.

Comment: Then have a look at PyQt 5.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25950049/creating-a-transparent-overlay-with-qt

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12334217/python-qt-2d-overlay-over-other-full-screen-app

Comment: Those don't look promising, the first failing on fullscreen modes (same as my solution) and the second with no answer. Ideally this would work on Mac OSX and Windows as a solution.

Comment: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/10547#issuecomment-331747125

Comment: Qt looks really promising -- with this https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwindow.html#fromWinId. Would that work in PyQT?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/chipolux/acf28d367822e20cc62672f49eb1aab7

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45061803/cannot-get-qwindowfromwinid-to-work-properly

Comment: https://programtalk.com/python-examples/PyQt5.QtGui.QWindow.fromWinId/